# State-of-the-art non-training based stereo matching algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network

In the world of 3D vision, constructing a 3D model from multiple view imagery is an important topic. The stereo matching step is one of the most crucial steps. Based on the benchmark of [KITTI2012](https://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=stereo) and [KITTI2015](https://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_scene_flow.php?benchmark=stereo), most state-of-the-art methods are training-based methods. I.e., algorithms need domain-specific training data to train the model.

On the contrary, the conventional stereo matching algorithms [SGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-global_matching) and [MGM](http://dev.ipol.im/%7Efacciolo/mgm/) don't need any kind of training data and they just work. One of the biggest drawback of training-based method is that it requires domain-specific training data to train the model. E.g., if I am working on a project which uses multiple view satellite imagery to build the 3D model of a city, I cannot use stereo images taken from dash cam on cars to train the stereo matching model for my project.

Thus, my question is that besides [SGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-global_matching) and [MGM](http://dev.ipol.im/%7Efacciolo/mgm/), are there more advanced stereo matching algorithms which are not training-based method, and they can just work on any kind of domains.